# transform variables then check for collinearity or other way round?

Tags: data-transformation, multicollinearity

I was planning to construct a model with around 19 explanatory variables and one response variable. I have some confusion on following thing:

If transformation is required in case of explanatory variables, do I transform first and then check for collinearity or the other way round

Sorry if the question is not correct or vague.

Thanks

Comment: When you have two questions, you should ask them as two separate questions here!  As for the second question, checking for colinearity must of course be done with the variables you are actually using in your model, so after transformation.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, the model that you use ought to have as little collinearity as possible because collinearity makes interpretation of your predictors difficult or even meaningless. So, after you've selected a model (with any transformations) you ought to check for collinearity. If transformation is required, transform and then check for collinearity because this is the way the variables will be used in the model.